# Taking screenshots with Mac keyboard

Tags: mac, screenshot

I have been using Ubuntu 10.04 on my HP notebook for more than two years, and I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on Mac Pro.

The problem of taking screenshots on a Mac is that there is no PrintScreen Key. So how can I take screenshots?

Comment: 10.04 LTS reached it E.O.L ages ago. I would consider upgrading. (On your HP notebook)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to upgrade to a newer version too.

Answer (score 12):

As there is no PrintScreen button on a Mac Keyboard,

- Go to `System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`
- change the shortcut to your favourite one.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Much quicker than opening Screenshot (which is excellent) and creating a screenshot.

Comment: I was in a similar situation with a new keyboard that is really for a Mac with no printscreen button.

Answer (score 5):

Open the dash and type "screenshot" you'll be prompted with an app, with a photo camera icon, that will let you take different types of screenshots.
You can grab the whole desktop or grab the current window or Select an area to grab.

While that app is open right click on it's icon in the launcher and select "lock to Launcher" to keep it there.

Comment: I just got "sorry, there is nothing that matches your search"

Comment: Try just typing 'screenshot'. That works for me.

Comment: The screenshot program name is localized, so e.g. in german you have to type "Bildschirmfoto"

Answer (score 1):

What I use is a program called Shutter. It works great and you can make basically any screenshot you want. It also sits down in a panel (at least in LXDE) so you can quickly use it. Hope this helps!